# How can I optimise this LinQ query?

Tags: c#, linq

```
model.mTable = m_ctx.Shop
 .Where(t => t.CustomerID== model.mFilter.CustomerID)
 .Select(f => new GroupedData
  {
      iGroupID = f.iCustomerID,
      dtGroupDt = new DateTime(f.dtDate.Year, f.dtDate.Month, f.dtDate.Day, f.dtStartTime.Hours, f.dtStartTime.Minutes, f.dtStartTime.Seconds, f.dtStartTime.Milliseconds),
 })
 .OrderByDescending(f => f.dtGroupDt)
 .Take(2)
 .ToList();
```

Shop is the table and CustomerID is the primary key of the table but if there is a lot of data then this query is giving me timeout exception. Is there any way to optimise this query?

Comment: yes. may be if he purchase some item on daily basis. Exactly CustomerID is a dummy kind of thing. If i say i need it for suppose kind of realtime data  which refresh after may 5 10 min.!

Comment: Does it change anything if you put the order before the select? But why do you have a column for each datetime portion instead of just a single `dtGroupDt`-column of type `datetime`?

Comment: Probably using  `OrderByDescending(t => t.dtDate).ThenBy(t => t.dtStartTime)` before the `Select` will be faster.

Comment: I would do what FrozenDeath said, but I would also try grabbing the query it generated and see if you can build an index around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 things that should help you here:

1) Combine `dtDate` and `dtStartTime` into a single column, if possible
2) Create an index on `dtDate` (see @TimothyStepansky comments) and then
3) Reorder how you execute your query (untested, syntax might not be entirely correct):

```
model.mTable = m_ctx.Shop
              .Where(t => t.CustomerID== model.mFilter.CustomerID)
              .OrderByDescending(t => t.dtDate)
              .ThenBy(t => t.dtStartTime)
              .Select(f => new GroupedData
              {
                  iGroupID = f.iCustomerID,
                  dtGroupDt = new DateTime(f.dtDate.Year, f.dtDate.Month, f.dtDate.Day, f.dtStartTime.Hours, f.dtStartTime.Minutes, f.dtStartTime.Seconds, f.dtStartTime.Milliseconds),
              })
              .Take(2)
              .ToList();
```